# strcpy c function not work IOS C custom library for IOS7

Tags: c, ios7

I am using C for a custom IOS library. Now I have upgraded my XCode to 5.0 developer preview. Now **strcpy** not work for me its crash the app at that point. Anyone can explain me what is the issue?

**Update**

Here is my code:

```
char global[] = " ";
printf("Error opening %s for constants input\n", lang); 
strcpy(global, lang);
```

In `printf` lang is working and its but strcpy not working.

Comment: `strcpy` works fine. Your code has a bug. You'll need to find that bug and fix it. My crystal ball is currently broken so I cannot tell you what your bug is.

Comment: Post the code. What have you done?

Comment: @NJMR Here is mycode char global[] = "    ";printf("Error opening %s for constants input\n", lang);
 strcpy(global, lang); In printf lang is working and its but strcpy not working

Comment: @ShinningRiver Please don't post code in comments. Edit your question to include it and then you can format it.

Answer (score 5):

When you declare `global` as

```
char global[] = " ";
```

It only is enough space for *two* characters. The space and the string terminator. Either set a size big enough to contain the whole string you try to copy to it, or make it a pointer and allocate it dynamically (in which case you should not forget to allocate space for the string terminator).

Comment: In lang I have a string of 5 character like "av-dv". Its work perfect in xcode 4.6 but create problem in Xcode 5

Comment: @ShinningRiver Please realize that if someone of repute here says "your code is broken because X", it's more polite of you try to understand X than say "no it's not, it worked for me". Code can be perfectly broken yet still *happen* to work when you test it, that's one of the joys of unsafe programming languages. :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is there any safe programming language, given your context of safe?

Comment: @ShinningRiver That's the joy of [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), you can't really predict how it will work. Sometimes it crashes, sometimes it *seems* to work (but you overwrite data somewhere, making something else unrelated possibly not working).

Answer (score 1):

Avoid using `strcpy`, unless you are absolutely sure you have enough space in the target array.

Try this for a safe version. It still works quite bad, because `lang` probably does not fit, but it is safe.

```
char global[] = " ";

// alternative 1
snprintf(global, sizeof global, "%s", lang);

// alternative 2, more lines but also slightly more efficient
global[0] = 0;
strncat(global, lang, (sizeof global) - 1); // -1 needed to allow room for '\0'
```

For reference, man pages of [`snprintf`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/system/conceptual/manpages_iphoneos/man3/snprintf.3.html) and [`strncat`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/System/Conceptual/ManPages_iPhoneOS/man3/strncat.3.html).

---

To solve the space issue, you should *probably* make `global` big enough to hold all possible `lang` strings, *if you know the limit and it is reasonably small*:

```
char global[16] = ""; // room for 15 characters, contents initialized to all 0
snprintf(global, sizeof global, "%s", lang);
```

Alternative is to use dynamic memory:

```
int bufsize = strlen(lang) + 1;
char *global = malloc(bufsize); // contents uninitialized
// can't use sizeof, it would give size of pointer, not allocated buffer
snprintf (global, bufsize, "%s", lang);
...
free(global); global = NULL;
```

For using dynamic memory, also check out `asprintf`, documented in same man page as `snprintf` (link above).

You can also consider using Variable Length Arrays of C99, though if variable name is `global`, it will probably not work for your case:

```
char global[strlen(lang) + 1] = ""; // +1 for '\0', contents initialized to all 0
snprintf (global, sizeof global, "%s", lang); // now sizeof works again
// global is unallocated when it goes out of scope
```

Note that with dynamic memory, where you allocated enough memory for current contents of `lang`, you *could* use `strcpy` too, because then it is a case where you *do know* it fits safely. Still, using safe versions may be more robust against future modifications introducing new bugs.

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause for the error is that the `global` array is not long enough to contain `lang`. Without knowing the value of `lang`, we cannot say for certain. As it stands, if `lang` contains more than a single character and the null-terminator, then the call to `strcpy` results in buffer overrun.

You need to make sure that `global` is large enough to contain the contents of `lang`. You state in a comment that `lang` is an iso language code of the form `"**-**"`. The example you give is `"ad-dv"`. If you are sure that `lang` is never more than 6 characters long (including the null-terminator) then you can write your code like this:

```
char global[6];
strcpy(global, lang);
```

The other obvious option is to allocate the string dynamically:

```
char *global = malloc(strlen(lang)+1);
strcpy(global, lang);
```

Remember to call `free(global)` when you have finished with the variable.

The other common failure mode for `strcpy` is that the source string is not null-terminated which also leads to buffer overrun.

Comment: Sorry I am not C developer.I have set it to  global = lang but its showing error for me.Array type char[5] not assignable

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand that.

Comment: @ShinningRiver `global = lang` is trying to assign to array variable, which is not allowed in C (except the special case of defining it and initializing from string literal, `char global[] = "foo";` is allowed).

Answer (score 0):

Being the writer of the original C-code I think it's in order for me to explain.

A more complete and accurate piece of the code:

```
char predictLanguage[] = "    ";

void openPredictionConstants(char* language){
  strcpy(predictLanguage, language);

  if ((file = fopen(strcat(DATFILEPATH, predictLanguage), "_constants"), ".dat"), "rb")) == NULL){
    printf("Error opening %s for constants input\n", filename);
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
  }
  // Code for processing if file is opened successfully
}
```

The `language`parameter is always a 5-char locale, i.e. "en-GB", "en-US" etc., so a statically allocated char array is fine for the job.

However, the `predictLanguage` parameter is only 4 chars long + 0-termination for 5 chars total. `language` is 5 chars + 0-termination for a total of 6 chars. In other words - and as several people already pointed out - `predictLanguage` is not long enough to contain the locale passed in `language`.

Under normal circumstances I would have initialized the char array with a defined length, like `char predictLanguage[6]`, but because I wanted to make sure `predictLanguage` didn't contain garbage I initialized it with an empty string.

Turns out I had a brain fart when counting out the spaces and came up with the incorrect length. The error just didn't manifest itself in iOS6.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826047/strcpy-behaving-differently-on-ios7 .

Comment: The joys of undefined behaviour!